# Different image quality from picamera capture to numpy array and path

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, opencv

The quality of capture from Pi Camera varies when captured to numpy array and when captured directly to a path. The former has more pinkish tint to it than the later.

**Why is that.?**

The code I used for capturing the images:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import cv2
import time

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
img = np.empty((720, 1280, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

start = time.time()
camera.capture(img, "bgr")
print("Trigger time: " + str(time.time() - start))
cv2.imwrite("array_capture.png", img)

start = time.time()
camera.capture("normal_capture.png")
print("Trigger time: " + str(time.time() - start))
```

The time taken to capture the image to numpy array is half that of direct path capture. So, **Is it related to de-noising of image.?**


**Image Captured to numpy array: 0.71 sec**
[image: Image Captured to numpy array]

**Image captured to a path: 1.52 sec**
[image: Image captured to a path]

Comment: Put trigger time for numpy after write.  Then you can really compare. I am curious

Comment: @jaromrax Doing so increases the trigger time to around 0.925 sec. But its still less than that for the path capture.

Comment: Could it be a compression issue? For example, maybe cv2 doesn't use filtering but picamera does. What are the sizes of the output files? You can check with `du normal_capture.png` and `du array_capture.png`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Picamera Documentation](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html) in part 3.5 of the basic recipes section:

> You may wish to capture a sequence of images all of which look the
>   same in terms of brightness, color, and contrast (this can be useful
>   in timelapse photography, for example). Various attributes need to be
>   used in order to ensure consistency across multiple shots.
>   Specifically, you need to ensure that the camera’s exposure time,
>   white balance, and gains are all fixed:
>
> To fix exposure time, set the `shutter_speed` attribute to a reasonable
>   value. Optionally, set `iso` to a fixed value. To fix exposure gains,
>   let `analog_gain` and `digital_gain` settle on reasonable values, then set
>   exposure_mode to `'off'`. To fix white balance, set the `awb_mode` to
>   `'off'`, then set `awb_gains` to a (red, blue) tuple of gains.
>
> It can be difficult to know what appropriate values might be for these
>   attributes. For `iso`, a simple rule of thumb is that 100 and 200 are
>   reasonable values for daytime, while 400 and 800 are better for low
>   light. To determine a reasonable value for `shutter_speed` you can query
>   the `exposure_speed` attribute. For exposure gains, it’s usually enough
>   to wait until `analog_gain` is greater than 1 before `exposure_mode` is
>   set to `'off'`. Finally, to determine reasonable values for `awb_gains`
>   simply query the property while `awb_mode` is set to something other
>   than `'off'`. Again, this will tell you the camera’s white balance gains
>   as determined by the auto-white-balance algorithm.
>
> The following script provides a brief example of configuring these
>   settings:
>
> ```
> from time import sleep
> from picamera import PiCamera
>
> camera = PiCamera(resolution=(1280, 720), framerate=30)
> # Set ISO to the desired value
> camera.iso = 100
> # Wait for the automatic gain control to settle
> sleep(2)
> # Now fix the values
> camera.shutter_speed = camera.exposure_speed
> camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
> g = camera.awb_gains
> camera.awb_mode = 'off'
> camera.awb_gains = g
> # Finally, take several photos with the fixed settings
> camera.capture_sequence(['image%02d.jpg' % i for i in range(10)])
> ```